# I need help making a video/photo gallery with html and javascript

Tags: gallery, photo

I know this has been asked before, but I can't find any thread that can exactly help me. I'm a bit of a noob, but I know my way around. Here's what I have so far:
HTML File
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/9757676/Website%20Stuff/Website.html
Javascript file:
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/9757676/Website%20Stuff/script.js

(it wouldnt let me post the code)

is there an easier way to do this, perhaps put all the images into an array? and I also need help making a next and back button, perhaps one problem can solve the other

Answer (score 0):

Check jQuery tools: http://jquerytools.org/demos/tabs/slideshow.html.
It has lots of good plugins that could possibly help you.